# laravel one to many Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-5.8, laravel-7

**hello i need help to solve this problem.**

**I'm trying to get "One to many" relationship Value In view. but i get error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"**

Supplier MODEL

```
<?php

namespace App;
use App\Purchase;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Supplier extends Model
{
     
     protected $table = 'suppliers';
     protected $fillable = ['party_id','suppliers_master_id','suppliers_unic_id','supplier_name','email','phone','address','city','state','pincode','GSTIN','delete_status'];



        public function purchases()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Purchase::class, 'suppliers_master_id', 'suppliers_master_id');
}


}
```

Purchase MODEL

```
<?php

namespace App;
use App\Purchase;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Purchase extends Model
{
     protected $table = 'purchases';
     protected $fillable =
```

['suppliers_master_id','suppliers_unic_id','party_id','supplier_name','GSTIN','bill_no','bill_date','bill_entry_date','total_bill_amount','phone','pincode','state','address','delete_status','part_no'];

```
}
```

CONTROLLER

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use App\Supplier;
use App\Billproduct;
use App\Purchase;
use App\Item_list;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
class PurchaseController extends Controller
{
    /** 
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */

    public function purchaseentrylists($suppliers_master_id)
    { 
      
        $entry = Supplier::where('delete_status','!=','NOT_DELETED')->find($suppliers_master_id);
        return view('purchase.purchase-entry-list',compact('entry'));

    }


}
```

ROUTE

```
Route::get('purchas/eentry/lists{id}', 'PurchaseController@purchaseentrylists')- >name('purchaseentrylists');
```

VIEW

```
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <th>SL-No</th>
             <th>BILL NO</th> 
             <th>BILL DATE</th>
             <th>SUPPLIES NAME</th>
             <th>BILL AMOUNT</th>
    
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody> 
      @foreach ($entry as $key=>$entrys)
                                 
            <td>{{ $key + 1  }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entrys->bill_no  }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entrys->bill_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entrys->supplier_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entrys->total_bill_amount }}</td>

    </tbody>
                          
      @endforeach


</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to actually call the foreign relationship.
You will need to call: `$entry->purchases or $entry->purchases()->get()` to get the **Purchases Collection** for a Supplier, which then can be iterated.

```
<tbody>
 @foreach ($entry->purchases as $key=>$entrys)
                                 
            <td>{{ $key + 1  }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entrys->bill_no  }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entrys->bill_date }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entrys->supplier_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $entrys->total_bill_amount }}</td>
@endforeach
 </tbody>
```

And in your Controller:

```
public function purchaseentrylists($suppliers_master_id) 
{ 
$entry = Supplier::where('delete_status','NOT_DELETED')
->findOrFail($suppliers_master_id); 

return view('purchase.purchase-entry-list',compact('entry')); 
}
```

Comment: im not understand can you post your answer

Comment: wen i returned  " return Supplier::find($suppliers_master_id)->purchases; "  this i get value but when i used foreach it showing error

Comment: i modified my code as your answer get error "Trying to get property 'purchases' of non-object"

Comment: You will probably need to use findOrFail() instead of find, or handle the case that you did not find a valid entry

Comment: can you update  public function purchaseentrylists($suppliers_master_id)
    { 
      
        $entry = Supplier::where('delete_status','NOT_DELETED')->findOrFail($suppliers_master_id);
        return view('purchase.purchase-entry-list',compact('entry'));

    } in your answer  thank you